# How to make "SUM(amount) over" window function work in MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql, sum, window-functions

I have the following MariaDB SQL statement that I need to be converted to a MySQL statement

```
SELECT *,
SUM(amount) over (partition by voteid order by allocationid) AS TotalAmountAvailable
FROM allocation
```

I get the following error message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by voteid order by allocationid) AS TotalAmountAvailable FROM alloca' at line 2

My company live server has the following setup:

```
Database server - Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 - (Ubuntu)
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Comment: MariaDB uses the same flavour of SQL as MySQL. Are you referring to any particular version of MySQL and a missing feature?

Comment: For some reason it's not working even though it may be the same flavour. I believe the MYSQL version is 5.7

Comment: Not working is not a very useful phrase. Are you seeing any results, any errors?

Comment: Error
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

An alias was previously found. (near "TotalAmountAvailable" at position 75)
SQL query: Documentation

SELECT *, SUM(amount) over (partition by voteid order by allocationid) AS TotalAmountAvailable FROM allocation LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by voteid order by allocationid) AS TotalAmountAvailable
FROM alloca' at line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, the problem is with the window `sum()`, which MySQL 5.7 does not support (while it is available in MariaDB starting version 10.2).

You could rewrite it as a correlated subquery:

```
select
    a.*,
    (
        select sum(amount) 
        from allocation a1 
        where a1.voteid = a.voteid and a1.allocationid <= a.allocationid
    ) TotalAmountAvailable
from allocation a
```

Comment: Good Day so my original query looks like the following how do I incorporate your result for this query with my original full query. I know that I didn't post the original query which works without the sum partition etc. Hope you understand what I mean :)

Comment: SELECT *, u1.user_name AS 'Created', u2.user_name AS 'Modified', u3.user_name AS 'Certified', SUM(amount) over (partition by voteid order by allocationid) AS TotalAmountAvailable, allocation.date_modified AS 'DateModified', allocation.date_created AS 'DateCreated'
FROM allocation
INNER JOIN user_details u1
ON allocation.created_by = u1.user_id
LEFT JOIN user_details u2
ON allocation.modified_by = u2.user_id
LEFT JOIN user_details u3
ON allocation.checking_officer = u3.user_id

Comment: @Ria: this is not the question that you originally asked. You might want to ask a new question for this.